# Why doesn't putting my own C library file into ld search path work?

Tags: linker

Currently I have two files

```
main.c
libxxx.a
```

main.c references some functions defined in the source code of a relocatable object file in libxxx.a.

Now the following command successfully compiles main.c and links it to libxxx.a:

```
gcc -o prog main.c libxxx.a
```

but if I put libxxx.a into one of the search paths of `ld`, the same directory with libc.a,

```
gcc -o prog main.c
```

just doesn't work. It seems that `ld` fails to find this archive file when searching in the directory. Can someone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

> but if I put libxxx.a into one of the search paths of lb linker, the same directory with libc.a,
>
> `gcc -o prog main.c`
>
> just doesn't work.

That is expected and desired: you wouldn't want *every* program you write to link against *every* library that is installed in the system search path. What you want is:

```
gcc -o prog main.c -lxxx
```

That is: copying the library into `/usr/lib` *allows* the linker to find it without any extra search arguments, but you *still* must tell the linker that you want to link against `libxxx`.